# Proof of stable matching

Tags: algorithm

I am currently working on a proof that requires this lemma to be proven true.

Suppose I have two distinct stable matchings P and Q for lets say n hospitals to n patients. I will construct a new matching with the following rule:

For each hospital h who is matched to two students s and s' in P and Q, h matches to its preferred student between s and s' in R.

I would like to show two things: (1) R is a matching and (2) R is stable.

From what I can tell I am trying to prove that a stable matching exists between the ranges of two stable matchings. I feel like (1) is trivial because no matter what value I pick between s and s', I can rearrange the other preferences accordingly in order to obtain a valid matching. As for (2), I am unsure how to start going about proving that the matching is indeed stable. Any insights will be greatly appreciated for (1) and (2). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**It is a matching.**

Suppose hospitals **H** and **J** are both able to match to, and prefer to be matched to student **s** compared to each hospital's other alternative student. Since it is a valid option for both hospitals, this means one of these hospitals must be matched to **s** in **P**, and the other is matched to **s** in **Q**.

**s** must prefer either **H** or **J**. Whichever it prefers, suppose it is **H** (from **P**) without loss of generality, then the (**H**,**s**) match is an unstable pair in **Q** which contains the less favorable (**J**,**s**) match. In **Q**, **H** was matched to some other element which is less favorable to **H** than **s** since we assumed that **s** is the most preferable match out of the two decisions for both **H** and **J**. This means that in **Q**, **s** is assigned to **J** but prefers **H** and **H** is assigned to some other student, but prefers **s**. Therefore (**H**, **s**) is an unstable pair in **Q**, however it was given that **Q** is stable and has no unstable pairs. This last paragraph can be repeated swapping **H** & **P** with **J** & **Q** to come to the same conclusion if **s** preferred **J** (from **Q**) instead of preferring **H** (from **P**).

Therefore, via this contradiction, no two hospitals will ever select the same student under the stated algorithm. This means that every hospital will have a unique student matched, and every student therefore will have a unique hospital matched, and the result is therefore a valid matching.

**It is stable.**

Suppose it is unstable and there exists a pair (**W**, **x**) where hospital **W** prefers student **x** to hospital **W**'s current match, which we call student **w**. Furthermore, student **x** prefers hospital **W** to its current match, hospital **X**. In **P**, it cannot be that (**W**,**w**) and (**X**,**x**) were both matches, since (**W**,**x**) would be an unstable pair, and **P** is given as stable. Same reasoning applies to it being impossible that (**W**,**w**) and (**X**,**x**) were both matches in **Q**. Therefore (**W**,**w**) is from one matching, and (**X**,**x**) is from the other matching.

Suppose without loss of generality that (**W**,**w**) is in **P** and (**X**,**x**) is in **Q**. This means that in **Q**, **W** must have been assigned to another student, **w'**, and that **W** prefers **w'** over **x** (to prevent **Q** from being unstable). This means that when constructing the new current set, the choices for hospital **W** were either **w** (from **P**) or **w'** (from **Q**) with **w** being selected. However,from **W**'s perspective, **w** is less favorable than **x**, and **x** is less favorable than **w'**, so **w** is therefore less favorable than **w'**. This contradicts the rule that each hospital selects its most favored student since **W** selected the less favorable **w** when it could have chosen the more favorable **w'**.

This whole last paragraph can be repeated swapping **P** and **Q** to come to the same contradiction if instead (**W**,**w**) came from **Q** and (**X**,**x**) came from **P**.

This contradiction means that no unstable pair (**W**,**x**) can exist, which means the final matching is stable.

These possible stable matchings form a lattice which is a partial order. The algorithm you described is a lattice operator to move one step in this lattice towards the "optimal hospital" matching.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_of_stable_matchings#Lattice_operations